# Issues with implementing treeSort()

Tags: java, sorting, tree, binary-search-tree

So, my doctor asking me to implement treeSort() and then test it on int[1000000] and calculate the time.

I have class `BSTree<E>` which contains the following methods:

```
public void treeSort(E[] data)
{
    inorder(data, new Process<E>(), root);
}

public static <E> void inorder(E[] list, Process<E> proc, BTNode<E> p)
{
    if (p != null)
    {
        inorder(list, proc, p.getLeft( ));    // Traverse its left subtree
        proc.append(list, p.getElement( ));   // Process the node
        inorder(list, proc, p.getRight( ));   // Traverse its right subtree
    }
}
```

and I have `Process<E>` class:

```
public class Process<E>
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public void append(E[] list, E element)
    {
        list[counter] = element;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and I have the following `Main` class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] temp = {4,2,6,4,5,2,9,7,11,0,-1,4,-5};
        treeSort(temp);
        for(int s : temp) System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void treeSort(int[] data)
    {
        BSTree<Integer> tree = new BSTree<Integer>();
        for(int i: data) tree.insert(i);
        tree.inorder(data, new Process<Integer>(), tree.getRoot()); // I get an error here!
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
cannot find symbol - method inorder(int[], Process<java.lang.Integer>, BTNode<java.lang.Integer>); maybe you meant: inorder(E[], Process<E>, BTNode<E>);
```

I fixed that by changing `treeSort(int[] data)` to `treeSort(Integer[] data)`. But I got an error in the main method at `treeSort(temp);`

and the error is:

```
treeSort(java.lang.Integer) in Main cannot be applied to (int[])
```

So, how can I deal with this issue with taking into account not increasing the complexity time where I should try this method upon 1 million inputs?

Comment: you have the worst doctor ever.  Mine typically just charges me money to see him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer[]temp = {4,2,6,4,5,2,9,7,11,0,-1,4,-5};

EDIT: use it to fix second error.

Answer (score 0):

Generics cannot be basic classes. You can use Integer[] instead of int[], and rely on autoboxing.